# Implementing multiple interfaces having same method

Tags: java, oop, interface, overriding

This code works perfectly.  The method test() works for both interfaces.  What is exactly going on under the hood?  And how is this feature useful in practical scenario?

```
interface A
{
    void test();
}

interface B 
{
    void test();
}

class C implements A, B
{

    public void test() 
    {
        System.out.println("abc");
    }
}

   A a = new C();
   a.test();
   B b = new C();
   b.test();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java abstract class implements an interface, both have the same method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202185/java-abstract-class-implements-an-interface-both-have-the-same-method)

Comment: Please not even if the duplicate is about abstract classes and interfaces it is basically the same with two interfaces.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implemeting 2 interfaces in a class with same method.Which interface method is overridden?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801878/implemeting-2-interfaces-in-a-class-with-same-method-which-interface-method-is-o)

Comment: for usefulness have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html The `LinkedList` can be treated as `List`, `Queue` or `Collection` and `size()` would always return the same. This would not work if two implemented interfaces were forbidden to have common method signatures.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because it's an interface there is no harm done. You're basically using a blueprint for your `C` class by implementing `A` and `B`. Both `A` and `B` say that `C` should implement a method called `test()`

Your `C` class implements that method, so the interfaces have done their job.

It's basically your `C` class saying: "Oh hey, I need to implement `test()` because of interface `A`" and you implement it. Then your `C` class says "Oh hey, I need to implement `test()` again because of interface `B`" and it sees that there is already a method called `test()` implemented so it's satisfied.

You can also find more information here: [JLS §8.4.8.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.4)

Answer (score 7):

Suppose we have two interfaces...

```
public interface StockBroker{
        //Give our client some investment strategies.
        public String adviseClient(Client c);
}

public interface Doctor{
  //Examine our client and give them some medical advice
        public String adviseClient(Client c);
}
```

And a class implementing both interfaces....

```
public class JackOfAllTrades implements StockBroker, Doctor{
   public String adviseClient(Client c){
   }
}
```

While it may be syntactically correct to implement both interfaces with one method, you may not get the desired behavior.  For example, a stock broker and a doctor typically each give their clients vastly different advice.

Someone using an object that implements the interface `Doctor` expects the `adviseClient()` method to give medical advice.  But someone using an object that implements the interface `StockBroker` expects the `adviseClient()` method to give out investment strategies.

In this case, the object `JackOfAllTrades` does not know what type of advice to give out because the `adviseClient()` method has no parameters telling it which interface it is supposed to be implementing when `adviseClient()` is called.

This is a shortcoming in Java because the person designing the `Doctor` interface may have had no way of knowing that someone else would design a `StockBroker` interface with the same method signature.

To anyone creating interfaces, its probably good practice to make the method names unique enough that name collisions are rare.

Answer (score 6):

[JLS §8.4.8.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.4) says,

> **Inheriting Methods with Override-Equivalent Signatures**
>
> It is possible for a class to inherit multiple methods with override-equivalent signatures (§8.4.2)
>   …
>   There might be several paths by which the same method declaration might be inherited from an interface. This fact causes no difficulty and never, of itself, results in a compile-time error.

It seems the rationale was that if a class has multiple declarations with the same name and signature, since the class may have inherited them through multiple paths—implementing an interface and also subclassing a class that implements that interface, for example—no harm is done.

Comment: What if the return type of the method is different in the two interfaces?

Comment: @premktiw Compile error. The key phrase in the JLS is *override-equivalent signatures*. It’s not legal to change the return type in an override.

Answer (score 2):

Not as far as syntax is concerned but if the `intent` of one of the `methods` is not adhered to, its contract is broken and the **code can be considered as broken**.

Using your analogy, if I promised Michael to wear a blue shirt instead of a red shirt, and I can't wear two shirts, then I will have to break at least one promise.

The same can hold for the methods: if keeping one contract would mean breaking the other then it's in fact a bad idea to `implement` both `interfaces`.

**Edit**:Contract broken, As per `Class C signature` It should implement two methods,but ultimately its implementing only one `method` and omitting another.

[Reference](http://www.coderanch.com/t/416996/java/java/class-implements-interfaces-method)

Comment: Can you explain where and how a **contract is broken** here ?

Comment: Contract broken, As per Class C signature It should implement two methods,but ultimately its implementing only one method and omitting another.

Comment: *It should implement two methods* ??? It should implement a method declared as `void test()` , where is the second one ?

Answer (score 2):

```
interface A
{
void test();
}

interface B 
{
void test();
}
class C implements A, B {

    public void test() 
    {
        System.out.println("common to all");
    }
    public A choose(A a){
        return new A(){
           public void test() {
                System.out.println("test of A");
           }
        };
    }
    public B choose(B b){
        return new B(){
           public void test() {
            System.out.println("test of B");
           }
        };
    }
}
class Demo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   C c =new C();

   A a = new C();
   B b = new B();

   a = c.choose(a);
   b = c.choose(b);

   a.test();
   b.test();
   }
}
```

Comment: Code with no explanation isn't an answer