# Two interfaces with same method name, what happens when I override?

Tags: java, interface, overriding

So I have a class 'MyClass' & two interfaces 'A' & 'B'

```
public class MyClass implements A, B {

    @Override
    public void mymethod(){
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }

}
```

...

```
public interface A {
    void mymethod();
}
```

...

```
public interface B {
    void mymethod();
}
```

What method from what interface here is being overridden?

I'm thinking both are?

Thanks
(student)

Comment: I suppose in this situation it doesn't really matter which one, is there a situation where is *would* matter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Multiple Inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824402/java-multiple-inheritance)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing multiple interfaces having same method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484325/implementing-multiple-interfaces-having-same-method)

Comment: @KevinPaton: you are correct.

Comment: @KevinPaton yes there is a situation where it would matter if the methods have different signatures...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it will be like there is only one method.  It will override "both" methods in this case because they have the exact same signatures.  If the methods had different signatures (return type or something) then there would be a problem. Check out this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801878/implementing-two-interfaces-in-a-class-with-same-method-which-interface-method)

For Example:

```
public class MyClass implements A, B {

    @Override
    public void mymethod(){
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }

}
...

public interface A {
    void mymethod();
}
...

public interface B {
    String mymethod();
}
```

This would cause a problem...

Answer (score 1):

It would be both since it conforms to both interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
((A)(new MyClass())).mymethod();
((B)(new MyClass())).mymethod();
```

outputs

```
hello world
hello world
```

It's straightforward to test what **can** happen.

If you encounter this then there's potentially some common feature between A and B that could be abstracted to another interface that A and B both extend, or there's undesirable shared terminology between them causing the overlap and something might need renamed.

Answer (score 0):

An interface is just a contract.

Implementing A means `MyClass` should have a method `void mymethod()`.

Implementing B means `MyClass` should have a method `void mymethod()`.

It's overriding "both", but I am not sure this is a proper way to say it.

It's just about filling a contract and making sure MyClass has the proper method.

Comment: You are not overriding the methods, you're implementing them.