# Two Interface with same method name is showing error

Tags: java, interface

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

interface animal{
    void bark();
}

interface reptile{
    void bark();
}

public class Interface implements animal, reptile {  //Type interface must implement abstract method reptile.bark() {
    public void reptile.bark()             // Duplicate method bark(), invalid returntype
        System.out.println("wowwow"); 
    }

    public void animal.bark(){           //Duplicate method bark(), invalid  returntype
        System.out.println("hsss");
    }

}
```

Above is my code. I have two interfaces with the same functions. My spring tool suite keeps on showing the errors mentioned in the comment statements. How to solve these errors?

Comment: What makes you think `public void reptile.bark()` is valid syntax? There's nothing like C#'s explicit interface implementation (which is what it looks like you're trying) in Java. (It would also make your post clearer if you would format your code.)

Comment: Then how can i implement both the bark methods in same class?

Comment: If you are happy with just one implementation, you can just use `public void bark() { ... }`. But you can't give the two interfaces different implementations. As an aside, it's a good idea to follow naming conventions - and naming a class `Interface` is definitely misleading...

Comment: A quick search would've led you to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484325/implementing-multiple-interfaces-having-same-method)

Comment: is reptile not an animal?